# Segmentation fault - weird debugging with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I'm working in C, Linux terminal. I need to find a pattern in a text and recolor it. GDB debugging can locate the function that is causing the problem via (gdb) backtrace, but it shows me a terrible message when I try to find the exact line:

Error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strstr_sse2_unaligned ()
at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S:40
40 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or dir
ectory.
(gbd)
```

The broken function is find_and_recolor:

```
char* my_replace(char *text, char* replacement)
{
      int lgreplacement = strlen(replacement);
      int lgtext = strlen(text);
      char *aux = (char*)malloc((lgreplacement + lgtext + 10) * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(aux, replacement);
      strcat(aux, text);
      return(aux);
}

char* find_and_recolor(char* text, char* pattern)
{
      int lgpattern = strlen(pattern);
      int lgreplace = lgpattern + 10;//there are exactly 10 characters that must be inserted along the pattern word
      int dif = 0;
      char *p;
      char *replacement = (char*)malloc(lgreplace * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(replacement, "\e[0;31m");
      strcat(replacement, pattern);
      strcat(replacement, "\e[m");//to recolor a word in red, that word must be surrounded by those characters
      while(p = strstr(text + dif, pattern))
      {
            p = my_replace(p, replacement);
            p += lgreplace;
            dif = p - text;
      }
      free(replacement);
      return strdup(text);
}
```

Comment: Regarding *`strstr-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or dir`*, I believe you can install `glibc-dev` (Debian) or `glibc-devel` (Fedora) to clear the missing source files.

Answer (score 3):

> it shows me a terrible message when I try to find the exact line:

There is *nothing* terrible, weird or unusual about this message, you just need to learn proper debugging technique.

What's happening is that the segmentation fault doesn't happen in *your* code, it happens inside GLIBC code (inside `strstr`), because you called `strstr` with bad arguments.

To find which call to `strstr` that was, use GDB `up` command to step out of GLIBC code, and into your code. Once you are inside `find_and_recolor`, you would be able to see the exact line, and print values of `text`, `dif` and `pattern` which caused your crash (assuming you compiled your code for debugging, i.e. with the `-g` flag).

Answer (score 0):

Updating diff to `p-text` in while loop where both pointer points to different array doesn't make sense. It is undefined behavior.

Also code has other issues.

1. Uninitialized variable.
2. Less optimized as number of call can be reduced.

Comment: p is pointer towards a location in text array. So it makes sense to calculate a difference. Example: strstr finds the pattern at position 5 in text array, p moves to text + 5, so the difference will be p - text = 5.

Comment: No my_replace function return pointer to newly allocated  array in that function. Try printing address of p and text.

Comment: You are right... Also, I know the number of function calls can be reduced, but I just need it to be done in any method. No need for efficiency.